# usage of "featured in something" in everyday English

Tags: phrase-usage

I know what this phrase means, but should you use it only when something is *definitely* an important part of something else? Or is it just used interchangeably with 'included in'?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "feature" means *a distinctive attribute or aspect of something*, so for something to "feature" in something else it must be at the very least *noticeable*. I would expect it to be a significant part of something, but how large a part would depend on how many other featured components there were.

A good example of this in TV and movies. The *featured cast* are the main stars. Sometimes a difference between "starring" and "featuring" is drawn to emphasise one or two big names from everybody else. Other actors with a lesser role are referred to as the *supporting cast*, and those with perhaps non-speaking parts as *background* or *extras*.

If someone said that someone, or something "featured in a movie" I would expect that it would be noticeable, prominent, and in the foreground.

"Including" doesn't mean that you *wouldn't* notice the thing included, but it doesn't necessarily mean you would see it, either. One definition of "including" is "*containing as part of the whole being considered*". So, for example, if you tasted a product that "included" a particular ingredient, you wouldn't necessarily notice it individually, but it would contribute to the overall flavour as it is "part of the whole". On the other hand, if you said "I took all my family on vacation including my mother" nobody would think that your mother went unnoticed.

Comment: Hey Astralbee, thank you very much for your helpful answer. So I conclude that it is not used interchangeably with 'included in'.

Comment: @NimiAbna It depends on context - "including" means the thing is in there somewhere, but it isn't necessarily as visible, if at all. If you said "all my family came with me, including my mother" you would certainly know that your mother was with you; on the other hand, if you said a product "included a secret ingredient" you wouldn't necessarily know what it was, or be able to discern it.